# JavaScript Check to see if Windows Restarted

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in JavaScript, to check to see if your computer restarted or is this a hopeless cause?

-Thanks

Comment: You can't make system level calls like that with JS for security reasons.

Comment: depends what you are doing. Do you want to let a website check this? Or are you using nodejs?

Comment: From within a browser?  What are you even trying to accomplish?  Any time a page loads that page's JavaScript application is re-loaded.  If you're trying to determine whether a computer has *ever* restarted at *any* point in the past then you can probably safely assume the answer is "yes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopeless cause. JS doesn't have access to the System.

Comment: Isn't this just an awesome candidate for a comment.

Comment: @hex494D49 I dunno, it seems to directly answer the question, don't you think?

Comment: @Mathletics I think you've missed my point. This just shows how unfair are people on SO. I believe someone else would get a whole package of downvotes for this. There are great questions being marked as unclear, off-topic and whatsoever while these kind of answers are awarded with a couple of upvotes. Shameless!

Comment: @hex494D49 I didn't vote on either the question or the answer. This question is so totally bogus it renders the answers irrelevant. That said, in the spirit of Q&A, this _answer_ does actually answer the question. Sometimes the answer really is "_no, you can't do that_." I'd save your indignation for worthier battles. Or don't, it's the internet after all.